# sql trouble creating table (foreign/ref key)(oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key

Cannot figure out these errors. been working on this far too long please help, I have been stuck on this for about 4 hours.

```html
CREATE TABLE Student
(
student_id varchar(25),
student_name varchar(25),
major varchar(10),
gpa number(3,2),
PRIMARY KEY(student_id)
);


CREATE TABLE Class
(
schedule_num varchar(25),
semester varchar(25),
course_name varchar(25),
course_number varchar(25),
credit varchar(4),
department varchar(25),
meeting_time varchar(25),
meeting_place varchar(25),
class_size_limit varchar (25),
PRIMARY KEY(schedule_num,semester)
);


CREATE TABLE Enrolls
(
semester varchar(25),
grade varchar(2),
PRIMARY KEY(student_id,schedule_num,semester),
student_id varchar(25) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Student(student_id),
schedule_num varchar(25) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Class(schedule_num),
);
```

2 errors---

1) ERROR -- missing right paren line 6
2) ERROR -- table or view does not exist line 1

Comment: I assume you're getting the error defining the `enrolls` table.  The primary key definition doesn't look sensible-- none of the three components of the key are actually columns in the table.  You also wouldn't use `FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES`, the syntax is just `REFERENCES`.  I'd expect that you want to use `varchar2` rather than `varchar` but that's not causing your issues.

Comment: So we don't need foreign key at all? What do you mean by does not look sensible?

Comment: You try to define a composite primary key on `enrolls`.  That composite key is comprised of three columns-- `student_id`, `schedule_num`, and `semester`.  `student_id` is not a column in the table.  `schedule_num` is not a column in the table.  It does not make sense to have a primary key that includes columns that don't exist.  Either you want to include those columns in your table (which seems sensible) or you want to define the key differently.  The syntax for defining an inline foreign key constraint does not include the literal words `foreign key`, just `x references tbl(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you should use `varchar2()` rather than `varchar()` (for very arcane and historical reasons).

When defining foreign and primary keys:

- The foreign key needs to exactly match the primary key.
- The `references` keyword does not use `foreign key` when inline with the column definition.
- A composite foreign key cannot be declared in line.
- A column needs to be defined before it can be used in a constraint.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b9827) is a SQL Fiddle that fixes these problems:

```
CREATE TABLE Student (
    student_id varchar2(25),
    student_name varchar2(25),
    major varchar2(10),
    gpa number(3,2),
    PRIMARY KEY(student_id)
);


CREATE TABLE Class (
    schedule_num varchar2(25),
    semester varchar2(25),
    course_name varchar2(25),
    course_number varchar2(25),
    credit varchar2(4),
    department varchar2(25),
    meeting_time varchar2(25),
    meeting_place varchar2(25),
    class_size_limit varchar2(25),
    PRIMARY KEY(schedule_num, semester)
);

CREATE TABLE Enrolls (
    semester varchar2(25),
    grade varchar2(2),
    student_id varchar2(25) REFERENCES Student(student_id),
    schedule_num varchar2(25),
    FOREIGN KEY (schedule_num, semester) REFERENCES Class(schedule_num, semester),
    PRIMARY KEY(student_id ,schedule_num, semester)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added an extra comma at the end of your second last line.
schedule_num varchar(25) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Class(schedule_num)**,**

That comma is possibly causing both the errors.